# I could not use Apache cordova dbcopy plugin

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I wrote some html/js codes for db management in apache cordova/android. 
Firstly i wanted to copy a sqlite db to my project. 
i used a plugin for this. dbcopy. 
I read docs. 
And i wrote some codes. But it is not working. in some functions, i wrote some alerts. But they are not working. 
I am using jquery mobile in apache cordova. 
My codes;

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
    
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
      <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
           
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sqlDB.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 

                function dbcopy()
                    {
                            //Database filename to be copied is demo.db
                            alert('copy is starting');
                            //location = 0, will copy the db to default SQLite Database Directory
                            window.plugins.sqlDB.copy("ogrenci.sqlite", 0, copysuccess,copyerror);

                    }

                  
                    function copysuccess()
                    {
                            //open db and run your queries
                            alert("copysuccess");
                             db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "ogrenci.sqlite"});.
                    }

                    function copyerror(e)
                    {
                            //db already exists or problem in copying the db file. Check the Log.
                            console.log("Error Code = "+JSON.stringify(e));
                            //e.code = 516 => if db exists
                    }
                    dbcopy();



        
})
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Arif's App</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            
           

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Copyright 2016</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
             
 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First: It is not a good idea to load jQuery from an external source. It slows down your app and the user gets traffic (costs). But if you want to go this way, you have to whitelisten the url. Second: Before your code starts, you have to listen for the cordova deviceready event, read the docs!!

Comment: Thank you for reply. Sorry for first. Because code snippet putted the external source jquery. in my project, there is no external source.
I wanted to use with jquery. I saw cordova deviceready event. But i was thinking about it is like jquery $(function(){}) event. 
And i used camera function with jquery. 
But i will try with cordova deviceready event this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the plugin? you can install to your project by running the following command on your cordova project directory:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dbcopy`